# Ending PLSQL procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I wrote a PLSQL procedure in Oracle APEX, but I don't know how to end it as every way I have tried it still complains.

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE FzgZuordnen(Volt VARCHAR2) IS
Variable Declarations
*
    BEGIN
    *
    END;
FzgZuordnen END;
```

I have also tried

```
     *
     END;
END;
```

But it doesn't seem to like any way I end my procedure. I have ended all of the things inside the procedure.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I remove declare it complains at finding procedure and replaces procedure with declare.

Comment: FYI. all blocks need an internal statement.. so you could try adding a `NULL;` between the begin and end

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a **local** procedure in a PL/SQL block anywhere - including in APEX.  The syntax is like this:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE FzgZuordnen(Volt VARCHAR2) IS
    -- Variable Declarations
  BEGIN
    -- Procedure code
  END FzgZuordnen;
BEGIN
  -- Block PL/SQL that calls the procedure  
END;
```

For example:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE raise_error (error_text VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    raise_application_error (-20001, error_text);
  END FzgZuordnen;
BEGIN
  if :p1_value < 0 then
    raise_error ('Value cannot be negative');
  elsif :p1_value > 10 then
    raise_error ('Value cannot exceed 10');
  end if;
END;
```

Because the procedure is declared locally it can only be used from the PL/SQL block where it is declared.  If you needed a procedure that could be called from many placed in your application or page then it would need to be defined in the  database (preferably in a package).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you cannot place PL/SQL procedures directly in an APEX page. For PL/SQL execution there are APEX processes. If you have to re-use your code on other pages then either copy the process to each page or use a db procedure (meaning putting the procedure directly in the database)

---

**Using APEX process:**
Create a new Process on the Page and select "PL/SQL Code" as type. Then type your Code into the APEX process.

```
Variable Declarations
*
BEGIN
*
END;
```

Processes can only be used inside the same page. If you want to use your code on multiple other pages you have to copy them to this page.

---

**Using DB-procedure:**
If you use a db procedure you have to add it directly to the oracle database. Therefor connect to the database with a tool of your choice. Execute your code from above. To call the procedure in APEX use something like this.

```
begin
    PKG.FzgZuordnen(:APEX_PAGEITEM);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE FzgZuordnen(Volt VARCHAR2) IS
  Variable Declarations
  *
  BEGIN
  *
  END FzgZuordnen;
BEGIN
*
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plsql procedure inside a database schema using sql developer or sql plus

```
create or replace procedure zgZuordnen(Volt VARCHAR2) IS
 .. variable declaration
begin
    {statament blocks}
end zgZuordnen;
```

From APEX frontend developer option you can call the procedure with bind variable